# Locking in Google Realtime DB

Tags: synchronization, identity, google-drive-realtime-api, mutual-exclusion, collaborative-editing

I see that google provides api for javascript to collaborate: all clients see the same model. The undates (I believe between `model.beginCompoundOperation` and `model.endCompoundOperation`) are claimed to be atomic and durable. This seems to be ideal for single controller - multiple viewers (which refresh on model update) but seems insufficient for concurrent applications, IMO. As far as concurrent controllers are conserved, inconsistent model can result when they all start manipulating the model disregarding the others.

Consider identity counter. You maintain a graph. That is your model. Every node must have their own id. There is single nextID value, in the model. When client creates a node, it increments that field. However, you understand that another client can do the same thing at the same time. They both have incremented the counter from 4 to 5. However, two nodes were added. This demonstrates that shared data access must also provide locking interface. I do not see anything in Google Realtime API. It is not even discussed. Why nobody seems to notice and nobody seems to care?

Comment: Grant covered most of it, but just so there isn't any confusion.. The realtime API is not a database in the traditional sense.  Its a very different model from your standard ACID database, and hence does not require any locking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the concerns you have are quite valid for a database, however I would be skeptical about using the Google Realtime API to store data specifically the way that you are describing if you require your data model to have ACID properties. Some constraints that you reference are discussed [on this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/advanced-model#collaborative_math), and limitations and behavior of compound operations are [talked about here](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#grouping_changes_together).

Of particular interest, as far as your reference to compound operations, is the following from the [second link](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/build-model#grouping_changes_together):

> However, although edits made in a compound operation are delivered together, they are not atomic. It is possible that, because of conflict resolution, some edits in a compound operation will never be delivered.

The data model in the Realtime API runs conflict resolution on changes that you make to it rather than guaranteeing an operation is going to have an exact effect that you requested. Storing data structured as your describe and performing operations that require locking is not a good options. The [first link](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/advanced-model#collaborative_math) has a reference that describes how you can use the realtime model to perform shared math.

Comment: I welcome the correction of my invalid statement and example of how conflicts can be avoided with model adjustments but I do not understand how to solve other problems, which require locking common resource. Particularly, how this collaborative `conflict resolution` can generate identifiers for new graph nodes?

Comment: I'm not sure what your particular use case is, however if it is not a requirement that the identifiers for your graph nodes are incremented based on a value stored in the document, I would use a different method of identifying your graph nodes. For example, each collaborative object that you create is assigned a unique ID, you could use that to identify your nodes.

Generally though, if the operations you are performing absolutely require ACID and there is not an alternate way to perform the operation, you should consider using a different backing store that provides appropriate mechanisms.

Comment: It is nice to say `use unique id` in response to the question `how do I generate one?` :)

Comment: If you can use the ones from the collaborative object that works quite well. If that is not an option, using some combination of app start time, user account creation time or user ID, current time and a monotonic counter per-client is probably going to work fairly well. I'd search for GUID/UUID generation [http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt] if that doesn't feel sufficient.